Taylor coefficients are bounded in the Hardy space $H^1$
Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the open unit disc and let $H^1(\mathbb{D})$ be Hardy space formed by all analytic functions on $\mathbb{D}$ such that
$$
\|f\|_{H^p}:= \sup_{r \in (0,1)} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(re^{i\theta})| \,d\theta< \infty.
$$
If $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n \in H^1(\mathbb{D})$ then $|a_n| \leq \|f\|_{H^1}$. Any ideas on how to prove it? I thought about considering the formula of $a_n$ using the Cauchy integral and the derivatives, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Let $S$ denote the unit circle. Then given $f = \sum_{n} a_n z^n \in H^1(\mathbb D)$ we get
$$
|a_n| = \left|\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{rS} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right| \le \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{|f(re^{i\phi})|}{r^{n}} d\phi \le \frac{\|f\|_{H^1} }{r^n}
$$
for arbitrary $r \in (0,1)$. By considering limit under $r \rightarrow 1$ we conclude $|a_n| \le \|f\|_{H^1}$.

Thanks! There should be an $r$ inside the parenthesis of $|f(e^{i\phi})|$ right?

@ScottishQuestions Yes, it should be. I corrected the answer.
